# Разбиение переписки по дням

Tags: php

Приветствую, имеется что-то типа форума, в нем определенные темы и в них сообщения, есть время отправки сообщения(unixtimestamp). Нужно разбить эти сообщения на группы по дням. Понятно, что нужно сравнивать время отправки со временем начала и конца дня, но где брать эти времена? или может есть какой-то другой, более красивый способ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(date_field, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

PHP (используя удобный [функционал PDO позволяющий группировать строки](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo/fetch#FETCH_GROUP)):

```
$sql = "SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(date_field, '%Y-%m-%d'), * FROM forum";
$data = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

вернет массив ключами которого будут даты, а значениями - все записи за эти даты

Comment: неплохое решение, жаль что на проекте до сих пор mysql..